# Safely drop master key

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

I've restored a database in my Dev environment (SQL version 14.0.1000.169) and I'm using the wizard to create a "Availability Groups", when I try to select the database, I get a pop up "This database is encrypted by database master key, you need to provide valid password when adding it to the availability group".

So I ran the script below, which returned 1 row.

`SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101`

which I assume means that there is a master key created, and from what I gathered from the web, you can see what databases use the master key with the following script:

```
SELECT d.is_master_key_encrypted_by_server FROM sys.databases AS d where d.name = 'MyDB'
```

which returns 0 for my database.

So, of course I ran: 
drop master key;

The question is: What's the proper way to see if the master key is needed (if anything is using it)? How do test I if broke something.

Comment: If anything was protected by the master key, you'd get an error.

Comment: the error would occur when I try dropping the master key?

Comment: Yes, if it protected anything.